# LED Spotlights - Not Turning on (Despite Power being present)

Tags: electrical, wiring, led

I have nine [4" LED spotlights](https://www.amazon.ca/LUCKYWIN-Recessed-Ceiling-Junction-Dimmable/dp/B07PR67T4M?th=1) (9W each) running in the bedroom, they're recently installed in the bedroom on their own 15Amp circuit.

I had them running for a little while maybe 2 hours, and then then they all went off. I checked the breaker, its good, turns on/off without issue. No Arc Fault detected, no issues there.

I used a non-contact tester on each cable going into the lights - shows that they're energized. Each of them has power coming in.

**Any ideas what else I could check?** The switch doesn't work, one/two lights are on their own, but the rest are wired `**EDIT**` *via daisy chain* - each light links to the next. None of the 9 are working however.

So I performed the following:

1. Removed the boxes, installed new boxes - kept the lights attached.
2. (With new boxes attached) installed new lights
3. Removed all boxes and installed original simple bulbs with + - connections, connected via Wago connections.
4. Replaced the switch with a good known working switch Same. I wave the contactless wang over all of it - beeping to show power all down the line of each, including the bulbs.

But nothing is actually turning on. Anything else?

---

- RDMan was correct, turns out, there was a 'forgotten' set of cables covered in electrical tape with a wing nut on the end. After removal of the tape. They came alive!
- (Full disclaimer regarding my stupidity, the cables were above the new sheet(s) of drywall, totally missed them when laying out the spot light holes)

Comment: It's possible that there's a thermal breaker that has tripped in the first light in the chain, shutting off all the lights. I saw no indication of such in the product listing, but you may want to check the installation instructions.

Comment: **** EDIT - Correction, yes, the lights are "Daisy Chained" connecting from one to another. Apologies for the wrong term.

Comment: So I performed the following:
* Removed the boxes, installed new boxes - kept the lights attached.
* (With new boxes attached) installed new lights
* Removed all boxes and installed original simple bulbs with + - connections, connected via Wago connections.
* Replaced the switch with a good known working switch

Same. 

I wave the contactless wang over all of it - beeping to show power all down the line of each, including the bulbs. 

But nothing is actually turning on.

Anything else?

Comment: Please do _not_ put info like that in the comments. Many people won't find it here, and comments can get deleted by a mod, causing useful information to be lost. Instead, [edit] your question to include all relevant info. As an added bonus, you get _many_ more characters to be very clear about what you're communicating and can include formatting to help make it more clear and emphasize important parts. You can even leave out `edit` tags, as anyone can easily click the `edited <date>` link next to your name if they want to see edit history.

Comment: Also, "waving" a non-contact voltage detector past a piece of wire sitting on your workbench _can_ get a beep due to induced current caused by the movement of the detector. You need to simply _hold_ it next to a wire to see if you get a beep. I often get beeps on first testing a dead circuit because I've moved the detector too quickly. Better a false positive, though, than false negative - less likely to be fatal.

Comment: Please don't edit the answer into your question. You've correctly check-marked the answer that helped. I presume you've given it an up vote. Put a comment on that post to explain if you feel it's really necessary. However, in this case, it's good - it allows us to ask about this new found splice. Is it in a junction box? If not, that's a fire waiting to happen. Is the junction box accessible through the drywall? If not that's a code violation for _exactly_ this reason.

Comment: Please post a whole new question about how to fix this situation, including pictures of these wires.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check ALL of your connections.

The only logical way there is power to the driver boxes and the lights do not come on is from a loose or broken connection.

Check all the neutrals as well. If you used the Wago style connectors, sometime included with the lights, check that all wires are push into the connectors fully. Hot and Neutral..check the grounds, but they will not prevent the lights from working.

Finally, this should not affect all the lights, but be sure the pigtails from the driver to the lights are connected properly.

Comment: Thank you! tonight I'm going to spend some time to review, you're right, the connectors are all (cheaper) Wago style connectors... perhaps I'll remove the included connector and install actual WAGO's instead.

The only 'red herring' here is that each of the units were beeping telling me their energized, I thought if I had a break, the power would not continue to the next light in the series.

Comment: That is why you check the neutral connections as well.  you may have power and no neutral connection.

Comment: So I performed the following:
* Removed the boxes, installed new boxes - kept the lights attached.
* (With new boxes attached) installed new lights
* Removed all boxes and installed original simple bulbs with + - connections, connected via Wago connections.
* Replaced the switch with a good known working switch

Same. 

I wave the contactless wang over all of it - beeping to show power all down the line of each, including the bulbs. 

But nothing is actually turning on.

Anything else?

Comment: Have you verified that you have a neutral connection.  You need to get a voltmeter and verify that you have 120 volts between the hot and neutral.  If it's a not then you need to find the break in the neutral.

Comment: Thanks, I'm off to get the voltmeter and perform a trace. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Following the advice of RMDman, I went right back to basics. I started removing the drywall (FULLY) from the ceiling and digging around. It seems I had forgotten a single pair of twisted cables that had electrical tape and a wing nut around the ends. These cables somehow (goodness knows how) allowed the lights to work up until a point. And then... maybe due to movement stopped everything working.

Regardless, it wasnt all in vain, upon removing the drywall I had found a light box that was squashed and broken open. So I managed to replace that too.

THANKS AGAIN EVERYONE!!! **Check, Check and double check your work.**

Comment: Again, I ask, is this splice in a junction box that is permanently accessible (either through the drywall from below or from the attic above? If not, that's a code violation and fire waiting to happen!